# When I click on link it opens the two new tabs using jquery.This works in firefox but not working in chrome and IE

Tags: jquery

When I click on link it opens the two new tabs using jquery.This works in firefox but not working in chrome and IE.My Code is:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickme").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open("http://localadvertisingthatworks.com?lp_redirect_4779=http://marketing.localadvertisingthatworks.com/acton/attachment/6817/f-001f/1/-/-/-/-/A%20guide%20to%20Local%20Advertising.pdf&amp;wp-cta-v=0&amp;wpl_id=TbfyVCtDihutDKsQUF8xD62LGQTWMJ369hN&amp;l_type=wpluid");     
    window.open("http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/download_thanks/");
    
     
    
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<a class="inbound-button inbound-special-class" style="background-color: #2da8d2; border-color: #2da8d2; color: #fff; margin-right: 15px;" href="#" id="clickme" target="_blank"><i class="fa-download"></i>Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since chrome allows only one URL open per user action (clicking second time on your link will open second link) you must simulate opening ([working example](http://www.justinas.tk/two-links.html), just allow pop-ups, don't know why need that on chrome; can't use SO Snippet as it prevents new tab opening):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="inbound-button inbound-special-class" style="background-color: #2da8d2; border-color: #2da8d2; color: #fff; margin-right: 15px;" href="#" id="clickme" target="_blank"><i class="fa-download"></i>Download File</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#clickme").on("click", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // random ID that will not match any other link on page.
                    var id1 = 'mrl-by-jj-'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
                    var id2 = 'mrl-by-jj-'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

                    // create links
                    var a1 = $('<a/>', {
                        href: 'http://localadvertisingthatworks.com?lp_redirect_4779=http://marketing.localadvertisingthatworks.com/acton/attachment/6817/f-001f/1/-/-/-/-/A%20guide%20to%20Local%20Advertising.pdf&amp;wp-cta-v=0&amp;wpl_id=TbfyVCtDihutDKsQUF8xD62LGQTWMJ369hN&amp;l_type=wpluid',
                        target: '_blank',
                        id: id1
                    });
                    var a2 = $('<a/>', {
                        href: 'http://localadvertisingthatworks.com/download_thanks/',
                        target: '_blank',
                        id: id2
                    });

                    // append to body
                    a1.appendTo('body');
                    a2.appendTo('body');

                    // trigger click and remove from DOM
                    $('#'+id1)[0].click();
                    $('#'+id2)[0].click();

                    $('#'+id1+', #'+id2).remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```